# Match first number before occurrence that isn't specific numbers

Tags: php, regex

I am matching the first occurrence of numbers and a comma before a specific string.  But, I don't want to match a certain group of numbers.

**Lets start with some examples**

Numbers I don't want to match: 2013, 2014, 2015

"This is the 1 string in 2013 I want to match."

```
preg_match('/([\d,]+)\D*I want to match/', $str, $match);
```

*Needs to match: 1*

"This is the 1 string I want to match"

```
preg_match('/([\d,]+)\D*I want to match/', $str, $match);
```

*Needs to match: 1*

"This is the 1 string in 2012 I want to match"

```
preg_match('/([\d,]+)\D*I want to match/', $str, $match);
```

*Needs to match: 2012*

My current regex works for examples 1 & 3, but I need to add the additional functionality of example 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your regex like below.

```
([\d,]+)(?:(?:2013|2014|2015)|\D)*I want to match
```

And get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nB1xU1/2)

**Explanation:**

- `([\d,]+)` It would capture one or more digits or comma.
- `(?:(?:2013|2014|2015)|\D)*` Matches the string `2013` to `2015`. It it finds a non-digit character then the control transfers to the pattern next to the OR part ie, `\D` (*which matches any non-digit character*). `*` after the whole group makes the whole pattern to repeat zero or more times.

Code:

```
$str = <<<EOT
This is the 1 string in 2013 I want to match.
This is the 1 string I want to match
This is the 1 string in 2012 I want to match
EOT;
preg_match_all('~([\d,]+)(?:(?:2013|2014|2015)|\D)*I want to match~', $str, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2012
)
```

Comment: Can you add briefly how to match all occurrences with php?  This regex with preg_replace_all returns empty.

Comment: It just returns the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
/(?:([\d,]+)\D*201[3-5]|([\d,]+))\D*I want to match/
```

[**Online demo**](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/9YZ)

The command:

```
preg_match('/(?:([\d,]+)\D*201[3-5]|([\d,]+))\D*I want to match/', $str, $match);
```